# Condition not checked

Tags: android

```
if((!phonenumber.equals("9096350204"))||(!phonenumber.equals("+919096350204")))
  {


    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, "Booking Successful...", null, null);  


 }
```

At any condition it will send sms to receiver?Why?

Comment: Any numbers will be either different from `"9096350204"` or different from `"+919096350204"` so your condition will always be true. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You need `&&`:

```
((!phonenumber.equals("9096350204"))&&(!phonenumber.equals("+919096350204")))
```

or:

```
(! (phonenumber.equals("9096350204") || phonenumber.equals("+919096350204") )
```

because each string will return false for `.equals("9096350204")` or `.equals("+919096350204")` as no string can be both of them. (See [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))